# Using QuickLook to preview PDFs causes allocations to rise indefinitely

Tags: objective-c, memory, instruments, quicklook

I'm using Apple's sample code (verbatim) for [Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) using the QuickLook framework/QLPreviewController to display PDFs to users (PDFs are roughly 4-5 MB).

When running this code through Instruments, Memory Allocation grows. However, it never seems to dealloc. Is this a known issue or is Apple's sample code missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and even though the number of allocations increases, it keeps stable after some time. This is most likely due to a "warmup" of the engine used to display those PDFs. Some objects are created when the API is first called and kept in memory for reuse.

Also note that there is no memory leak.

[image: Allocations vs Leaks]